# Python 3.3 could not install pandas in Windows 7

Tags: python, pandas

> "RuntimeError: Python version 2.7 or >= 3.4 required.
>   Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\20149308
>   \appdata\local\temp\pip-build-lgub9c\pandas\"

This is the command I used:

```
python -m pip install pandas
```

Can anyone help me install pandas?

Comment: just type `pip install pandas` in yor cmd prompt

Comment: I think you have your previous python 2.7 in path,  move python 3 bin path ahead.

Answer (score 1):

The error message itself has the answer:

> RuntimeError: Python version 2.7 or >= 3.4 required

The version of Pandas you're trying to install doesn't support Python 3.3. [The latest version](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html) only supports 2.7, 3.5 and 3.6.

So you have two options:

1. Install a newer version of Python, either 3.5 or 3.6.
2. Install an older version of Pandas: [version 0.17 was the last with official support for Python 3.3](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17/install.html).

To [install a specific version with pip](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#installing-from-pypi), use:

```
pip install pandas==0.17
```

You'll also probably need to install a specific version of Numpy, because that's dropped support for Python 3.3 in later versions: [the release notes for Numpy releases list which versions of Python they support](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/release.html). The latest version of Numpy that supports Python 3.3 is version 1.11.1, so:

```
pip install numpy==1.11.1
```

Comment: "Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\20149308
\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-qid65w\numpy\"

Comment: What's the entire error that you get? Earlier lines in the error message might have more information.

Comment: Collecting pandas==0.17
  Downloading pandas-0.17.0-cp33-none-win32.whl (5.3MB)
    100% |################################| 5.3MB 76kB/s

Comment: Collecting numpy>=1.7.0 (from pandas==0.17)
  Using cached numpy-1.12.1.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
   File "c:\users\20149308\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-qid65w\numpy\setup.py
line 34, in <module>

Comment: , line 34, in <module>
       raise RuntimeError("Python version 2.7 or >= 3.4 required.")
   RuntimeError: Python version 2.7 or >= 3.4 required.

   ----------------------------------------
ommand "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\20149308
appdata\local\temp\pip-build-qid65w\numpy\

Comment: this is what iam getting

Comment: Hm, in that case it sounds like the Pandas 0.17 documentation might be wrong about supporting Python 3.3. Try with `pip install pandas==0.16`, and then decrease the version number until you can find something that works? If that doesn't help, it may be that you need to be specific about the Numpy version as well.

Comment: can you please tell me numpy least version

Comment: It looks like Numpy 1.11.1 is the latest version of Numpy that supports Python 3.3 - have added this to my answer.

Comment: numpy is not getting instaled still.....i tried with least and also latest version